# Nodejs code exited without doing anything in Lambda Function. How to fix?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, telegram-bot

I am a newbie at JS and AWS Lambda. I have difficulty making a code that using both Telegram API and OpenAI APi run properly. Basically Telegram chatbot takes a prompt and send to Dalle to request for a image which returns a url to display on telegram.

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const TelegramBot = require("node-telegram-bot-api");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();
const token = process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN;
const configuration = new Configuration({
   apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
   });
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  
  try {
   
    const result = async function generateImage(prompt) {
      return await openai.createImage({
        prompt: prompt ,
        n: 1,
        size: "1024x1024",
      });
    };
    
    bot.onText(/\/image (.+)/, async (msg, match) => {
      const chatId = msg.chat.id;
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Your image is being generated. Please wait.");
      const response = await result(match[1]);
      bot.sendPhoto(chatId, response.data.data[0].url, { caption: match[1] });
      });
    return {
      statusCode:200,
      body: JSON.stringify('End of Lambda!'),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

The code works on my local server but not when i move it to Lambda. The code basically just ran "successfully" and exited almost immediately without waiting for the prompt from Telegram chatbot. Really appreciate if anyone can advise and point me in the correct direction.

Comment: Try  to add logger and see what is going wrong. Example JSON.stringify with the logger messages to nail down the problem on server. Log the request and response. And important function calls.

Comment: What do you mean by "works on my local server"? Are you running a local Lambda stack? How is the lambda being called? Are you using API Gateway? I mean... when this lambda runs it sets the `onText` handler then... will die when the lambda spins down.

Comment: @DaveNewton No I am not using a local lambda stack. I meant when I ran it as native nodejs, without the exporting the lambda handler, it works on my local environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find a way to wait for the callback to execute, maybe creating a new promise like below:

```
await new Promise((resolve) => {
    bot.onText(/\/image (.+)/, async (msg, match) => {
      const chatId = msg.chat.id;
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Your image is being generated. Please wait.");
      const response = await result(match[1]);
      bot.sendPhoto(chatId, response.data.data[0].url, { caption: match[1] });
      
     resolve(undefined);

  });
});

return {
      statusCode:200,
      body: JSON.stringify('End of Lambda!'),
    };
```

Comment: With the caveat that lambdas are not long-lived. This requires the lambda to be executed (somehow) periodically to continually install the handler etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should await `bot.onText()`

I believe that because of the Async nature of your Lambda handler and not properly awaiting, it's exiting early.

Comment: `onText` sets the handler for the regex; there's nothing to wait for.

Comment: Yes but as the code directly after it is a return statement the code block within the Async function passed to onText is not executed by the time Lambda invocation completes.

Comment: Correct--but that's nothing to do with `onText` (which is not an async function, AFAICT), rather that Telegram messages come at an indeterminate time in the future. Chat bot endpoint lambdas are generally hit through API Gateway/similar, e.g., the **lambda** is a message handler.

Comment: Thank you guys. You guys are right, the issue was with the function bot.onText(). It was solved with the await and promise code by Fuad below. Thank you so much for your comments.